# How to disguise android xml clickable link in android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, hyperlink

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/privacyPolicyLink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:text="https://www.google.com"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColorLink="@color/text_blue"
       />
```

Thats the link and it is currently showing up as a url on my app, i want to hide the url and make it clickable, I know this is simple but i can't for some reason find the solution. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the text of the TextView to what you like.  
The code below sets a click listener for a TextView so that when clicked it will open a web page in your default browser.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = "https://www.google.com";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

You can set the text color of the TextView to be link like.

Comment: Thats not what I meant, The issue is not that its blue like a link, I want the text to be something else not the Url but still be clickable to direct you to the URL

Comment: Will there be any other text in the TextView?

Comment: yes I want the text to read, Privacy Policy,then when clicked to direct the user to the privacy policy link

Comment: So you want a way to open a web page by clicking the TextView?

Comment: yes, is that not possible, like an <a> link tag in html. Currently it works when you click the link, it takes you to the page. I just done want it to look like a url.

Comment: is tv the text view ID?

Comment: Yes, replace it with your id.